# How to Filter a List of Strings by their Labels

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have developed an application that displays ASCII art using a RecyclerView. Currently, the strings for the ASCII art are stored in the strings.xml file. However, I now realize the need to incorporate a spinner that can filter the strings based on a selected label. By default, the spinner should display all the strings without any filtering applied.

As a newcomer to Android development, I'm uncertain about how to implement this functionality in my app. I have searched on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find many relevant solutions specific to my problem.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance from someone who can help me with this issue.

Here is MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       
        initAsciiArts();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        try {
            MemeAdapter adapter = new MemeAdapter(asciiArts, this, recyclerView, this);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle the exception here
        }
}

 private void initAsciiArts() {
        try {
            asciiArts.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.troll_face1),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.troll_face3),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.troll_face4),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.troll_face_redeyes),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.trollFace6),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.trollFace7),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.nyan_cat),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.mrIncredible),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.mrIncredible2),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.wegogym),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.Awkward_Look_Monkey_Puppet),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.Ghostface),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.ussrFlag),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.apeMonkey),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.cat),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.cat2),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.discordLogo),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.onepunchMan),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.XD),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.putin),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.Jigsaw),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.icanseeyou),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.GG)
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

here is MemeAdapter

```
public MemeAdapter(List<String> memeList, Context mContext, RecyclerView recyclerView, MainActivity activity) {
        this.memeList = memeList;
        this.context = mContext;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        mSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        rewardGranted = mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false);
        this.binding = activity;
        yourClass = new YourClass();  // Move the initialization here
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();  // Create AdRequest once
        yourClass.intertitalAd(context);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MemeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);
        return new MemeViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MemeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {

            final String meme = memeList.get(position);

            holder.memeTextView.setText(meme);
            if (position == 0) {
                holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false)) {
                holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            holder.copyImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                try {
                    clickCounter++;
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    String monospaceText = "<font face='monospace'>" + meme + "</font>";
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("meme", meme);
                    if (clickCounter == 2) {
                        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show(binding);
                        }

                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return memeList.size();
    }
```